# VBA excel fill cell color according to txt file input

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new with VBA. I'm reading a tab delimited file and parsing it.
Each line in the file contains a row index, a col index and a label: for example:

```
0    0    "John"

1    1    "Lena"

9    14   "John"
```

I'm suppose to assign each label with a color, and fill the matching [row,col] with the assigned color.
A label may appear in more than one file line.
In addition I should create a legend (in a different place on the worksheet) which describes which label was assigned to each color.

In c# I would have used a dictionary: when I see a new label I check if this label exists in the dictionary and if it does I use its existing color, if not I add a new entry to the dictionary. 
What is the best way to do this in VB? What data structure I should use to check if the current label exists, and if it does, use its color?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Can you show structure of `.txt` file please?

Comment: Dictionary is available in VBA.  Early bind to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (`scrrun.dll`) or late bind to `Scripting.Dictionary`

Comment: How many different labels will there be? Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

How about this: I use the `ColorIndex` property to set the color of the cell by incrementing from `1` onwards:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Sub ReadTextFile()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, filePath As String, data As Variant, colorIndex As Integer
    filePath = "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\input.txt" //Change this

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading, False)
    colorIndex = 1

    Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
        inputLine = txtStream.ReadLine
        data = Split(inputLine, vbTab)

        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(CInt(data(0)), CInt(data(1))) = data(2)
            .Cells(CInt(data(0)), CInt(data(1))).Interior.colorIndex = GetColor(CStr(data(2)), colorIndex)
        End With

        colorIndex = colorIndex + 1
    Loop

    txtStream.Close
 End Sub

Function GetColor(label As String, colorIndex As Integer)
    If Not dict.Exists(label) Then
        dict.Add label, colorIndex
        GetColor = colorIndex
        Exit Function
    Else
        GetColor = dict(label)
    End If
End Function
```

The only bit I've not done is add the legend but I am sure you can just iterate over the dictionary and write to wherever you want it on the worksheet.